# How to query wikidata by name (fuzzysearch) and third-parties ID

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-api, knowledge-graph

I wish to leverage on wikidata (and learning a bit Sparql if necessary) for entity matching, and want to:

1. query an entity by its name AND by name of a list of properties (both fuzzysearch) => so to be sure in case of disambiguations! (CATS as cats, not proteins)
2. query an entity by the property ID of third parties (e.g. the external ID of  wikipedia, or Google Knowledge Graph).

__

About point 1.

I sneaked at the network request and read something like:

https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbsearchentities&search=cats&format=json&language=en&uselang=en&type=item

I looked at the documentation https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php 
It is full of parameters, but no examples to visually see what they do.

- Could you give an example, via API REST or directly in Sparql, to combine a full text search of the entity name and a list of properties, so to fetch the matching entity's wikidata ID ?

As per example in https://query.wikidata.org/

```
#Cats
#
# => Here I'd like to first query Q146 by its name or by a list of properties of Q146, and then pipe the query
#
SELECT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q146.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

About point 2.

How could I query an entity with a specified Property - like the ID of third parties, e.g. Google Knolwedge Graph ID - Property P2671 / Freebase ID ?

Comment: Point 2: Do you mean you have property and value given and are looking for entities that match?

Comment: web search via SPARQL: `SELECT * WHERE { SERVICE wikibase:mwapi { bd:serviceParam wikibase:api "EntitySearch" . bd:serviceParam wikibase:endpoint "www.wikidata.org" . bd:serviceParam mwapi:search "cat" . bd:serviceParam mwapi:language "en" . ?item wikibase:apiOutputItem mwapi:item . ?num wikibase:apiOrdinal true . } } ORDER BY`

Comment: Point 2 : @AKSW I mean a list of properties, and looking for entities that match. I tried your comment but got error `Query is malformed: Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 305`-  tried on https://query.wikidata.org/ . Would you mind to elaborate what it does, in term of syntax and parameters ? Have not found a correpondence with https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php

Comment: The query works for me with the Wikidata SPARQL endpoint. All it does is to is wrap the Wikidata search API inside SPARQL. Docs are here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual/MWAPI

Comment: Turns out ORDER BY was missing by "what" to order. If I exclude order by I see results.  thank you for appointing a doc a start.

Comment: ah, right - my bad. just omit the `order by` then. It's just for ranking the search results